# Why isn't this span centered within this h1?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why this doesn't result in the "Table of Contents" text being centered. I'm trying to understand fundamentals and use best practices but am in need of a little direction.

HTML:

```
<div id='main'>
  <h1><span id='toct'>Table of Contents</span></h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

#toct {
  margin: auto;
  width: 10%;
}
```

[image: h1]

Comment: Because a span is an inline element, and `margin:auto;` only works on block elements with a set width. Use `text-align:center;` on the `<h1>` instead

Comment: @JacobGray, this might not work, you might also have to make the `span` have `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb only if the OP wants the width to be applied. If that is the case, the better option would just be to set the `<h1>` to `width: 10%`, with `margin:auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this snippet. I made the background lightblue so you can see the `<h5>`. `<h1>` wouldn't fit in the box.

```css
#main{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
}#toct {
  margin: auto;
  width: 10%;
}
h5{
  background-color:lightblue;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <h5><span id='toct'>Table of Contents</span></h5>
</div>
```